# ST_Union based on attribute

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql

I have a road network of center lines of MultiLinestrings. They have nodes at every intersection. I try to understand how I can merge roads together that have the same category as  attribute (there are about 80 different categories). Roads with the same category are not always connected, so I guess I need to have the result back as a MultiLineString again but grouped on attribute value.

Is there a way to do this?

Edit:
I played around some more and almost got the result I wanted. 
Simply using

```
SELECT  "category", ((ST_Collect(geom))) as geom FROM s.road GROUP BY "category"
```

But this seem to be returned as a Geometrycollection of Multilinestrings and cannot be loaded into QGIS.
Any advice?

Edit 28.07

Final solution:

```
SELECT  "category", ((ST_Union(geom))) as geom FROM s.road GROUP BY "category"
```

Using ST_Union instead of ST_Collect gave me the results I wanted. For beginners in SQL like myself can I explain why. ST_Union dissolve overlapping and overlapping regions whereas Collect does not. The consequences using ST_collect in this case with MultiLineString is that the result is a Geometry collection that is not a supported type for QGIS to load.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT category, ST_Union(geom) geom FROM s.road GROUP BY category;
```

You might want to use [ST_Dump()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) afterwards not to have multilinestrings in the result.

Comment: Thanks I tried, but it did not work for me. 

I Have however got it into Linestrings (10k<) and now need to get the Linestring with the same category to create a MultiLineString.
Never done these things before, am I completely out?

Comment: What happens with ST_Union?

Comment: Use ST_Multi() to promote linestrings to multilinestrings.